# How to select first row of each table?

Tags: r, sqlite

I have a SQL database with 30 tables ordered by company names. They are 30 stocks. Each table has columns date, high, low, close and volume.

My question is: how do I select the first record of each table in SQL?

Is it

```
FROM TOP 1 * SELECT aaple_30min?
```

I tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM bac_30min
LIMIT 1
```

but this gives me only for one table.

I have decided to write the query in R, where I will loop through the companies in question and use the paste function to make calls by replacing above "bac_30" with company names as strings.

Comment: You really need to change your table design. Don't create seperate tables for every company.

Comment: But if for some reason you are stuck with this design, the syntax is `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM aaple_30min`

Comment: OP wants to do that automatically for every table.

Comment: There is no easy way to do that in SQL, because it's not how SQL is intended to be used. You are putting data in your table names - your data should only be stored in table *rows*. Instead of one table per company name, you should have a single table with a `company` column. Then your query is much simpler, and you don't have to dynamically add and delete tables when you modify which companies you're tracking.

Comment: ok i see thank you

Comment: This is more of a design issue. The course i am taking required creating separate tables, one for each company, hence 30 tables since the dates were used as keys for the time series of prices.  I agree that having one table for separate companies would be helpful.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.